# Add persistence.xml from EJB dependency in arquillian test

Tags: testing, jpa, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I have a web maven application that have the *database* EJB jar as a dependency.

The *database* EJB is the one which has all the JPA entities and the persistence.xml file, so it's responsible by all database operations.

I just read http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/ and it explains how to test persistence using arquillian.

The tutorial considers that the persistence.xml file is in the webapp path, so it adds META-INF/persistence.xml as a resource.

So I'd like to know, how do I add database's persistence.xml when running the arquillian tests from my webapp? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer comes a little late, but anyhow I hope it's still of value for you:

You have two options, either read the archive from a file (maybe generated my mvn package) or create the archive yourself using ShrinkWrap:

Option (1), called from somewhere annotated with @Deployment:

```
/** maven did it for us .. we just have to read the file */
private static Archive<?> getArchiveFromFile() {
    JavaArchive artifact = ShrinkWrap.create(ZipImporter.class, ARCHIVE_NAME).importFrom(ARCHIVE_FILE)
            .as(JavaArchive.class);

    return artifact;
}
```

Option (2), I found it useful to inspect the file from time to time so there's an option to write it to the file system:

```
/** doing it the hard way ... guess you won't like it as EVERY class plus related stuff needs to be specified */
private static Archive<?> getArchiveManually() {
    // creating archive manually
    JavaArchive artifact = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, ARCHIVE_NAME)

            .addPackage(FooServiceBean.class.getPackage()).addPackage(Foo.class.getPackage())
            .addPackage(FooService.class.getPackage()).addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml");

    // so we might write it for further inspection
    if (WRITE_ARCHIVE) {
        artifact.as(ZipExporter.class).exportTo(new File("D:/abc/xyz/tmp/" + ARCHIVE_NAME), true);
    }

    return artifact;
}
```

So your answer is included within the second option ;-)